# Is there any way to conform that the file is encrypted

Tags: encryption, data-files

I have a file 'T019.T19975.ITEM.BARCD.DATA' and i'm trying to read this file but i can't see the data.

os -linux,

I tried some command on this like

file T019.T19975.ITEM.BARCD.DATA

T019.T19975.ITEM.BARCD.DATA: SysEx File -

file -bi T019.T19975.ITEM.BARCD.DATA

text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

head T019.T19975.ITEM.BARCD.DATA

> �������@@@@@������`��`������`��`��@������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@@@@@������`��`������`��`���������������������������@@

Comment: Looks too regular to be encrypted. Where did you get this file? What is supposed to be in it?

Comment: Actually i'm working on this file, and i have no idea about the exact data so i want to see the contents. it should be some data in forms of table. Is there any command to check whether the this file is encrypted or not?